# Can't find drives on Debian VPS on a XenServer

Tags: debian, fstab

I've rebooted my VPS and afterwards the VPS can't find the extra added drives. During boot the VPS gives following message in the console:

```
fsck.ext3: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/xvdc1
/dev/xvdc1: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

fsck.ext3: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/xvdf1
/dev/xvdf1: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

fsck died with exit status 8
failed (code 8).
File system check failed.
```

When running those commands the system can't find the drives. And I continued to boot the VPS. Everything booted but the extra drives (with valuable data) can't be found anywhere.

```
vps:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            4.0G  3.0G  764M  81% /
tmpfs                 1.1G     0  1.1G   0% /lib/init/rw
tmpfs                 1.1G  4.0K  1.1G   1% /dev/shm

vps:~# fdisk -l
vps:~#

vps:~# ls /dev/ | grep xv
vps:~#
```

My fstab is:

```
vps:~# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>               <dump>  <pass>
/dev/xvda1      /               ext3    rw,noatime              0       1
/dev/xvdb1      none            swap    defaults                0       0
/dev/xvdc1      /home           ext3    rw,noatime,usrquota     0       1
/dev/xvdf1      /mnt/backup     ext3    rw,noatime              0       1
/dev/tmpMnt     /tmp            tmpfs   loop,noexec,nosuid,noatime,rw   0       0
```

How is this possible? How can I fix this?

The system can boot from the `/dev/xvda1` partition it seems, but afterwards it can't be found. And also the additional drives (with valuable data!) are missing!

Comment: What does the output show: `lsblk`.

Comment: @slm
vps:~# lsblk
-bash: lsblk: command not found

Comment: How about `blkid`? Be sure to try full paths too: `/usr/bin/lsblk` and `/usr/bin/blkid`.

Comment: @slm
`vps:~# /usr/bin/lsblk
-bash: /usr/bin/lsblk: No such file or directory
vps:~# /usr/bin/blkid
-bash: /usr/bin/blkid: No such file or directory
vps:~#`